# Couldn't remove the video source attribute

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have 4 buttons in a page. Each button is having 4 video paths but the video tag keeps playing the first path I have given to it for all 4 buttons. This is how I tried solving it:

```
  function PlayRecordedWordSoundFile(x)
        {
            debugger;

            var video = document.getElementById('vidplayer');
            var sel=x;
            video.pause();
            video.removeAttribute('src'); // empty source
            video.load();
                var source=document.createElement('source');   
                source.setAttribute('src',"/x/"+sel);
                video.appendChild(source);
                video.play();


        }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="Listen" title="Listen" class="normal-but btnlistenB" value="Listen" data-id='<%# Eval("videoFilePath") %>'>Listen</button>
<video  id="vidplayer"></video>
```

```
   $(document).on('click','.btnlistenB',function(){
            PlayRecordedWordSoundFile($(this).attr('data-id'));
            return false;
        });
```

Each button should be playing its own defined path. I have shown only one button demo since all of them are identical. Can anybody tell me what I have been doing wrong here?

Comment: When are you calling `PlayRecordedWordSoundFile`?

Comment: How is `PlayRecordedWordSoundFile` linked to button click?

Comment: its a scenario in my current project but atleast its just a function in a button click i have called this function

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are not using the same `id` for all the buttons. Also since you haven't added the button click listener, I'm just using an `onclick` listener on the button here.
Check this working [codepen](https://codepen.io/Nuhman/pen/jRgNzV?editors=1010) here.

```
<video id="vidplayer" width="670" height="377" autoplay="true" controls="controls">
    <source id="vidsrc" 
        src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" 
        type='video/mp4'>
</video>

<button type="button" id="Listen" title="Listen" class="normal-but btnlistenB" 
  data-id='http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4' 
  onclick="PlayRecordedWordSoundFile(this.getAttribute('data-id'));">
       Listen
</button>
```

And then,

```
function PlayRecordedWordSoundFile(x) {
    var video = document.getElementById("vidplayer");
    var source = document.getElementById("vidsrc");
    var sel = x;
    video.pause();
    source.removeAttribute("src"); // empty source
    video.load();   
    source.setAttribute("src", "" + sel);   
    video.play();
}
```

Comment: can u make sure that it would play for another button as well cus its still didint work for me and i have used a gridview for the button so its a single button.

Comment: This code as it is should work for another button also. It would be in everyones interest if you show how you call the `PlayRecordedWordSoundFile` function, I believe.

Comment: So have you tried this code? Make sure you have `source` element inside `video`.

Comment: yes i have tried but the thing that got me stuck is whenever iam clicking  button all path is appending to the video tag just have to empty it i guess